# Movie with a space murder

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a movie. The scene I remember is two astronauts in a spaceship room, both wearing full astrosuits. One intentionally pulls a lever (or something) with causes a hatch to open, revealing space. This hatch is window-size, and there are a few thick prison-like bars to it. As it opens, the other astronaut is pulled decompression-style towards the hatch. When he touches the bars, he gets brutally chunked. This was intentional.

I have watched this scene around the 90s. Any ideas?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This is a good to know list. Unfortunately, this scene scared me so much back then, that I instantly stopped watching. I truly remember nothing else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a good match for the opening scene of [Saturn 3](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_3). YouTube link:

Comment: Added the scene from youtube for George to be able to check.

Comment: @shade thank you. Can't get onto YouTube for some reason. Internet connection bis too glitchy.

Comment: Yepp, surely that. The ominous music, the perp being black...things that I've forgotten, but came up instantly. Thanks!

Comment: Youtube Clip of the scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSd5IUqB0BE